# Redirect to third party site not using browser third party's own cookies

Tags: spring, authentication, redirect, cookies, browser

I'm developing a web application on spring that uses a third party identity service.

The identity service allows logout by navigating to example-site.com/logout. Whenever I navigate manually from my browser, my session's cookies are sent and the endpoint identifies me and logs me out.

However, when I try to redirect to the endpoint from my application, like this:

```java
//(my-app/logout -(response.sendRedirect())-> identity-site/logout)
http.logout(logout -> logout.logoutSuccessHandler( 
  new LogoutSuccessHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String host = getIdentityServiceURL();
        response.sendRedirect(host+"/logout");
    }})
```

The browser does not send the cookies stored for the identity service, and I'm never logged out.

Is this the intended behaviour? If it is not, how can I code the redirection so the browser sends the cookie?